# pygame on windows set window border color and/or window border text color

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pygame

Is there a way to set the border color for the pygame window, not the background, but the area were the close, maximise, and minimize buttons are

Comment: That cannot be set. It is system specific. Unless of course, you want to remove it altogether and make your own version.

Comment: what do you mean system specific? If you mean the themes, i tried changing it, but id diddnt seem to do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That cannot be set. It is system specific. Unless of course, you want to remove it altogether and make your own version. –